# Creating a compound index on a single array field

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I want to create an index on a field that will hold arrays. By default, mongo indexes each item in every array separately when an index is created on such a field.

However, I want the index to instead be a compound index, similar to an index on a subdocument field (I want the index to be unique, and `['a', 'b']` to be distinct from `['b', 'a']`). Is there any way to do this in monogo?

Comment: Does it have to be an array?

Comment: Well, it needs to be some sort of arbitary-length multi-value field. An array is the only thing that fits the bill that I know of...

Comment: You could store it in a string, `"a,b"` and handle individual elements in the app.

Comment: the values can have different types, and I want to maintain their identity

Comment: Realize that the key length cannot be longer than 1024 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by storing the data as follows:

```
{ 
    field: { v: [ a, "b" ] }
}
```

And then do an index on:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { field: 1 } );
```

I know it's a bit counter intuitive, but an index on "field" will now use as index value:

```
v: [ a, "b" ]
```

And not each a and "b" individually. Of course you can use something else for "v", but it is important that the value for field is a document, and not an array.

A query on:

```
db.collection.find( { field: { v: [ 'a', 'b' ] } } )
```

Will then happily use the index:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor field_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "field" : [
            [
                {
                    "v" : [ "a", "b" ]
                },
                {
                    "v" : [ "a", "b" ]
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "whisky:27017"
}
```

Comment: Does that actually use an index though when using the compound value in a query? I think it won't.

Comment: Sure, I've clarified my answer.

Answer (score -1):

For the question of whether it uses the index when you index on a wrapping field, yes it does use an index. The following statements from the shell prove that.

```
> db.arrayindtest.insert({_id:1, f:{a:["a","b"]}})
> db.arrayindtest.insert({_id:2, f:{a:["b","a"]}})
> db.arrayindtest.insert({_id:3, f:{a:["a","b", "c"]}})
> db.arrayindtest.ensureIndex({f:1})
> db.arrayindtest.find({f:{a:["a","b"]}})
{ "_id" : 1, "f" : { "a" : [  "a",  "b" ] } }
> db.arrayindtest.find({f:{a:["a","b"]}}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor f_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
        "nscanned" : 1,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "f" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "a" : [
                                                "a",
                                                "b"
                                        ]
                                },
                                {
                                        "a" : [
                                                "a",
                                                "b"
                                        ]
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "sridhar-PC:27017"
}
>
```